# Tower (GIT) custom script?

Tags: git, terminal, git-tower

I am new to Tower. What I am trying to do is prevent pushing the repo to our remote if a file in the repo called index.html contains a string "1234".

Any suggestion?

And, if Tower does not allow that, can it be done when using git straight from terminal?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found a solution that works for me.

As far as the pre-push hook goes, it actually does exist. (This is just to answer the comment VonC left).

As of git 1.8.2 the pre-push hook can be run. So, what I am doing is exiting with a non zero value from the pre-push hook when I try to push and a certain file I specified in the pre-push hook contains a certain string.

So I guess that does what I needed to do. I can see that doing this on the server side is better, but in this situation I needed it to work this way.

So, by using git 1.8.2 it can be easily accomplished by using the pre-push hook.

Comment: Excellent. I missed that in https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/RelNotes/1.8.2.txt. +1 I have edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't seem to be related to Tower, but more linked to the remote repo itself:
You could setup (at that remote repo) an [update hook](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks#Server-Side-Hooks), which will examine each commit, and make sure the content isn't a faulty one.
See an example in "[Prevent pushes to git containing tabs in certain files (e.g. `*.cpp`, `*.h`, `CMakeLists.txt`)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4145628/6309)".

A client-side hook like a "pre-push hook" wdel>does *not* exist, so it is best to mutualize that control on the remote side, in order to enforce that control for any downstream repo pushing to said remote repo.

The pre-push hook actually exists [since git1.8.2](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/RelNotes/1.8.2.txt) 5March 8th, 2013), but that requires deploying it to each downstream repos, which is not optimal compared to enforcing that same policy in *one* place (the upstream repo).
That being said, if you have one downstream repo you are working with (i.e your own local repo), a pre-push hook sure can come in handy.

Comment: So, I've read some of the hook docs and still working on it to get a better understanding of that, but, could using the pre-push hook allow me to make this happen client side and abort the push by returning a non zero value in the hook?

Comment: @zumzum a "pre-push" hook does **not** exist: to enforce a policy for *all* downstream repo, it is best to add a hook on the remote side.